# Detect when JavaScript is turned back on?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

No, I don’t want to know how to sense when JavaScript is off at page load. I have a MutationObserver that maintains page state in a fast and efficient way. If the user turns off JavaScript while the page is up, then turns it back on later, I have missed those mutation events, and my state is out of sync.

I can deal with it with a scan of the page then, although it is slow. A setInterval scan would be too costly. But I would like to sense it is back on, as soon as possible. How could I do it? Something that senses I have missed an event? But the browser would not send an event during the JS off time.

I need a creative way to tell that the DOM was changed by the user when JavaScript reactivates, before I process any subsequent mutation events.

Comment: You would need JavaScript to attach listeners to hear a hypothetical "turn on" event which is a chicken/egg problem. Users typically either have it on from the start or disable it at the agent level or through an extension. Considering uMatrix makes you refresh a page after you re-enable, I dont think there is any mechanism for this.

Comment: How does unmatrix make the user reload?

Comment: How does the user "turn off javascript"?

Comment: In Safari it’s Develop-> Allow JavaScript to off. I’m not sure about other browsers. I was thinking of a setinterval that just saves a time every second, and if I get an event that is more than that age I know there was a gap, since the user would have turned it off for at least that long.